# Scientific poster by an industry researcher: What do I put as contact information?

Tags: industry, poster

I am working at a consulting firm as a Data Scientist. I applied and was accepted to talk at a scientific conference. I am going to talk about a topic I worked on mostly during office hours and which has also been presented to customers by me.

At the conference there is going to be a poster session. I plan to put my company in the acknowledgments. What contact information should I put into "contact information" regarding a) my email address, b) the telephone number, and c) the address? My private, my company's? I lean towards private email and phone number and company's address. What do you think and why?

Comment: Is the research that you are presenting affiliated with the firm for whom you work? Did you conduct it outside of work, independent of your typical duties?

Comment: It was mostly worked on during office hours and has also been presented to customers.

Answer (score 16):

If your work was supported by your employer, then you should use your company address to acknowledge the affiliation. If it's work done in your spare time that is not sponsored by your employer, use your personal details.

Don't bother with the phone number – in academia, it's generally considered bad etiquette to call someone unexpectedly (unless it's an emergency).

Use whichever email address you wish – if it's a "professional" address like firstname.lastname@domain.com, it doesn't matter. You might lose access to your email address if you change employer, so it's also important that you use an address you'll have access to for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 7):

If the content you are presenting was created on company time, then you should put down your business contact details. Just as you would in interacting with a client. This is a professional interaction.

If the content you are presenting was created in your spare time, you should probably use your private contact details. (But discuss this with your manager.)

Alternatively, think about adding *both* email addresses. And add a link to your LinkedIn account, as well. (Use a [URL shortener](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=url+shortener) if it is too long.) In industry, your affiliation may change (even) faster than in academia, so your business email address could be obsolete in six months, with no forwarding.

Think about embedding your contact details in a QR code. People can simply scan it and have your details directly in their mobile device.

---

I am in a similar position. I use my business contact details for work-related research, much/most of which I do in my spare time. In addition, I do stuff that is in no way related to my day job. By agreement with my manager, I also use my business address for that work.

Comment: How do I add my linkedin account? The url is so long...

Comment: If all the other attendees of the conference are academics, you might not get many new connections on LinkedIn... @user49283 use a URL shortener, and/or a QR code

Comment: I edited the answer along the lines @Moriarty suggested at the same time.

Comment: I don't think that adding two addresses is ever a good option - it is convenient for a person presenting it, but confusing for the reader. What I do is using my personal email and business affiliation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have done the research during your work hours and using your company's resources, you should definitely provide the company's address. However, when it comes to the email id, it would be preferable to include your personal id, as you would not have access to your professional email in case of a job change.